# How to execute function on the object inside the template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have simple handlebar template:

```
'<h1>Order number: {{orderNumber}}</h1>'
```

That works fine.

Now I have situation where object that I pass it for render has a function to return itself id. It goes like this:

```
'<h1>Order number: {{orderNumber}}</h1><h2>Order ID:{{getId()}}</h2>'
```

How can I make Handlebar execute getId() and place its value instead?

**My failed attempt.**

Template:

```
'<h4>Order number: {{orderNumber}}</h4><h4>{{#getId }}</h4>'
```

Registered function:

```
hbs.registerHelper('getId', function(param, opts) {
  //return param.getId()
  return 666;
});
```

No matter what I try I always get this error:

> "Parse error on line 1:\n...{{#getId }}\n-----------------------^\nExpecting 'OPEN_INVERSE_CHAIN', 'INVERSE', 'OPEN_ENDBLOCK', got 'EOF'"

If I remove getId from the template, then it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create new Handlebars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getId', function(param, opts) {
  return 1;
});
```

Then you can call it using:

```
<span>{{getId someParam}}</span>
```

Comment: I tried, and cant get it to work. Can you please check my edite question?

Comment: Do you use this syntax to call helper `{{#getId someParam}}` ? No `()`, `#` at beggining. `Handlebars.registerHelper` - also important, it's global registration

Comment: When I inspect the handlebar object, I can see that my function is registered in helpers.

Comment: Yes, sorry - no need `#` here - it uses when you need closing tag at the end. Your case: `{{getId param}}`. Or, add close tag `{{/getId}}` if you need to manage data inside this tag.